# Laravel 8 Target class does not exist. [App\Http\Controllers\registerController]

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I just created a simple page in Laravel and when I run the file I got the error:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\registerController] does not exist.

I attached the folder structure below:

[image]

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\registerController::class, 'create']);
```

**createUser.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="{{url('create')}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" required>
    <hr>

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**registerController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class register extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('createUser');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file name and the class name doesn't match. Modify your `registerController.php` file as follows;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class registerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');

    }
}
```

And regarding the naming classes, I recommend using Capital camel case.

Comment: no sir it is getting same error.Target class [App\Http\Controllers\registerController] does not exist

Comment: Change the name into `RegisterController` for both filename and class name and then run `composer dump-autoload`.